# 2X1 Mux using mosfet

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

I tried to make a mux for implementing a carry  bypass adder(carry skip adder ).The image attached is the mux I tried in ltspice. But it is giving me from x no matter what S is(btw -S and -S are compliments ). Can you tell me where the error is ?[image]

Comment: I believe this type of analog mux requires a grounded body, not the more common body tied to source.

Comment: @Hearth, more specifically, the NMOS bodys should be grounded, but the PMOS bodys should be connected to the positive supply.

Comment: You need to use the 4-terminal MOSFET symbols (`nmos4` and `pmos4`).  Then tie the nmos bodies to VSS while the pmos bodies goes to VDD.  There's a reason why analog mux ICs require power rails.  If you plan on passing negative voltages, you'll need a negative supply for VSS.  GND won't cut it.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys !!!